# Trouble configuring Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins

When I go to run a ruby script as a build task, this is the error I get.
I am not sure what is wrong with the setup.

```
my RUBY_HOME "/home/bitnami/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374"
```

Any Ideas?

```
Started by user User Name
Building in workspace /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Test
[Test] $ ruby -v /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/hudson7369076924945073821.rb
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ruby" (in directory    "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Test"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this folder exist? /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/Test

Comment: It looks like `ruby` isn't in the `$PATH` of the shell that Jenkins started. Have you tried giving the absolute path (i.e. `/usr/bin/ruby` or similar)?

Comment: It seems like it was something to do with the ruby installation that was done through RVM.  Re-installed without RVM and now it works fine not sure what the problem was but glad its fixed

Answer (score 0):

To use RVM-managed ruby in Jenkins jobs, you have to source rvm in the build steps, like . /path/to/rvm/scripts/rvm. Then you need to set which ruby to use with rvm use. I use it extensively with no errors.